# Como fazer um cookie durar apenas uma requisição após ser criado em php

Tags: php

Boa tarde pessoal, minha duvida é como eu posso fazer para que um cookie dure só uma requisição em php

Comment: Você pode excluir o `coockie` assim que utilizá-lo na primeira requisição, mas qual seria a finalidade?

Comment: Você claramente não sabe o que significa uma requisição, se soubesse não faria sentido usar sessions, muito menos cookies. Tenta explicar pra gente o que você pretende obter como resultado final, o que você quer fazer e a gente te mostra o caminho.

Comment: Só estou usando ele para enviar um mensagem de erro ou sucesso, eu uso o setCookie() e faço um header() para onde eu estava, e peço em um lugar para mostrar a msg do cookie, mas queria q ela desaparece quando eu fizesse outra requisição

Comment: Acho que a ideia de colocar a mensagem de erro num cookie bem estranha... Eu entendo a lógica - usar o header pra redirecionar - mas ainda soa como gambiarra. Aconselho tentar não fazer assim, pois a chance de dar problema depois é grande.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na página de exibição do erro, basta você exibir o `cookie` e excluí-lo logo após:

```
<?php
  if (isset($_COOKIE["message"]))
  {
    echo $_COOKIE["message"];
    unset($_COOKIE["message"]);
    // ^-- Aqui você exclui o cookie após a primeira requisição.
  }
?>
```

> Lembre-se de definir um tempo de validade do `cookie` suficiente para que a próxima requisição seja feita, mas não tão grande a ponto de, se a janela for fechada antes da segunda requisição ser completada, exibir a mensagem de erro quando o usuário retornar a página.