# Jquery cookie - Exibir notificacação somente uma vez

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Preciso que seja exibido uma notificação assim que o login for feito, mas que, ao atualizar a página no navegador ou `F5`, a notificação não seja exibida novamente.

Usando o cookie, existe alguma forma de se fazer isto?

Abaixo o código que tenho

***Controller***

```
public function obter_mensagem()
{       
    $notificacao = array();
        $notificacao['mensagem'] = 'teste';
        $notificacao['tipo'] = 1;
    echo json_encode($notificacao);
}
```

***Javascript***

```js
console.log("master-page trabalhando");
/*** Variáveis ***/
var enum_toastr_type = { success: 1, info: 2, warning: 3, error: 4 }

/*** PageLoad Início ***/
$(document).ready(function() { 
 toastr.options = {
        closeButton: true,
        positionClass: 'toast-bottom-right',
        timeOut: '20000'
    }
    obter_mensagem_ajax();   
});
/*** PageLoad Fim ***/

/*** Métodos Início ***/
function exibe_mensagem_toastr(mensagens)
{
    $(mensagens).each(function () {

        switch (this.tipo) {
            case enum_toastr_type.info:
                toastr.info(this.mensagem);
                break;
            case enum_toastr_type.success:
                toastr.success(this.mensagem);
                break;
            case enum_toastr_type.warning:
                toastr.warning(this.mensagem);
                break;
            case enum_toastr_type.error:
                toastr.error(this.mensagem);
                break;
        }
    });
}
/*** Métodos Fim ***/

/*** Ajax Início ***/
function obter_mensagem_ajax() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
  async: false,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',        
  url : "helper/obter_mensagem",
        success: (function (data) {
   //console.log(data);
   _obj = JSON.parse(data);
            exibe_mensagem_toastr(_obj);
        }),
        error: (function (erro) {
            trata_erro_ajax(erro);
        })
    });
}
/*** Ajax Fim ***/
```

Comment: Se precisas disso só mesmo do lado cliente (o servidor não precisar dessa informação) então uma maneira melhor será https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage (localStorage), porque assim escusas de consumir banda desnecessáriamente com o cookie nas requisições/respostas

Comment: @Miguel, O servidor será necessário, pois farei validação de acesso, por exemplo; quanto tempo falta para o acesso expirar e notificar na tela.

Comment: Ha ok, sendo assim cookie é melhor

Comment: Te ajuda? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/190578/5878

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, Não consegui adaptar ao meu controller.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, este serva para verificar se o cookie existe.
Como faço para cria-lo utilizando o controller que tenho aqui ?